# How to directly pass Image into ArthurHub / Android-Image-Cropper for cropping

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using Jetpack compose for my UI, Activity Result Contracts and [ArthutHub Android Image Cropper Library](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/theartofdev/edmodo/cropper/sample/MainFragment.java) to crop images in my App. Everything works fine as expected with the following code:

```
val (result, launcher) = setUpContentPhotoCropImageIntent()//this activity result 
//contracts in launched on a button press
result.value?.let {
    //code here to save the image and show it in the UI, upload to cloud storage etc.
}

@Composable
fun setUpContentPhotoCropImageIntent(): Pair<MutableState<Uri?>, 
ManagedActivityResultLauncher<Any?, Uri?>> {

val cropActivityResultContract = object : ActivityResultContract<Any?, Uri?>() {

    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Any?): Intent {
        CropImage.isExplicitCameraPermissionRequired(context)
        CropImage.getPickImageChooserIntent(context)
        return CropImage
            .activity()
            .setActivityTitle("Choose Photo")
            .setCropMenuCropButtonTitle("Select")
            .setAllowRotation(true)
            .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON_TOUCH)
            .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE)
            .setAllowFlipping(true)
            .setOutputCompressQuality(100)
            .setFixAspectRatio(true)
            .setMaxCropResultSize(
                2000,
                2000
            )
            .getIntent(context)
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Uri? {
        return CropImage.getActivityResult(intent)?.uri
    }

}

    val result = remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(cropActivityResultContract) {
        result.value = it
    }

    return Pair(result, launcher)

}
```

So with this approach, the library takes care of not only cropping images but also capturing them via camera/gallery. I would like to pass a Bitmap image myself(by getting images using the built-in Android APIs to [Take Picture](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture) and [get Gallery Image](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.GetContent)) and use this library for just cropping, so that I can have 2 dedicated buttons for the user to either capture photo or choose from Gallery.

I have the image now, I want this library to just crop it for me, How do i Pass an Image into it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the latest library https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper

and them you can pass the image like this:

```
class MainActivity {
   private val cropImage = registerForActivityResult(CropImageContract()) { result ->
           if (result.isSuccessful) {
               // use the returned uri
               val uriContent = result.uriContent 
               val uriFilePath = result.getUriFilePath(context) // optional usage
           } else {
               // an error occurred
               val exception = result.error
           }
       }

   private fun startCrop() {
       // start cropping activity for pre-acquired image saved on the device and customize settings
       cropImage.launch(
           options(uri = imageUri) {
               setGuidelines(Guidelines.ON)
               setOutputCompressFormat(CompressFormat.PNG)
           }
       )
   }
}
```